# Voting system similar to SO in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC, and I'm trying to build a voting system, similar to stackoverflow.

I want that when I click on voteup button, to make a post on an action, make some checks there, but to remain on my initial page, and increment the vote (with js), if the checks passed (just like SO).

The items that I want to vote are populated by Index Action

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div><input type="submit" name="Vote" value="&#xf106;" class="fa fa-angle-up"/>
    </div>
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Votes)</div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="Vote" value="&#xf107;" class="fa fa-angle-down" /></div>
}
```

**Action**

```
    public ActionResult SendVote(string vote)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<VoteLogViewModel, VoteLog>());
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    switch (vote)
    {
        case "&#xf106;":
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Send to db
                VoteLogViewModel voteLogViewModel = new VoteLogViewModel
                {
                    DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    PlaceId = id,
                    UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                    Vote = 1
                };
                db.VoteLogs.Add(mapper.Map<VoteLog>(voteLogViewModel));
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            break;
        case "&#xf107;":
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Send to db
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            break;
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

How do I vote, without reloading the whole page?

Should I just make some links under my voting icons and somehow handle this with routes?

Comment: You need to use ajax to post the value if you want to stay on the same page.

Comment: You can write jQuery to call ActionMethod from controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use Ajax

Example:

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div><input type="submit" name="Vote" value="true" class="fa fa-angle-up"/>
    </div>
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Votes)</div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="Vote" value="false" class="fa fa-angle-down" /></div>
}

<script>
$(function(){
    $('input[name="Vote"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var result = e.data.value;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url // ActionURL,
        data: result,
        success: function(data) { //Success here },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SendVote(bool vote)
{
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<VoteLogViewModel, VoteLog>());
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    if(vote)
    {
        //Send to db
        VoteLogViewModel voteLogViewModel = new VoteLogViewModel
        {
            DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            PlaceId = id,
            UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
            Vote = 1
        };
        db.VoteLogs.Add(mapper.Map<VoteLog>(voteLogViewModel));
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
     //Send to db
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Please note it might not be syntactically correct since I wrote it in outside of an IDE. But this should get you going.

I also refactored your controller to use a `boolean` rather than switching on a string.

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason to keep them into a form, since the ajax click is triggered on click ?:)

Comment: @Stefan Good point. You don't really need the form if you use my approach. If you use StuRatcliffe 's approach then you still require the form.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` at data:result.

Comment: @Stefan in my post: 'Please note it might not be syntactically correct since I wrote it in outside of an IDE.'

Answer (score 2):

You're currently performing a full postback as in essence the HTML helper in your view is rending a standard HTML form.

You will need to trigger an AJAX post to the server if you don't want the whole page to refresh. If you are already including jQuery on your page, something like the following should work:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action(your action method)',
    data: {
        //form variables here
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
        //handle success
    },
    error: function(result) {
       //handle error 
    }
});
```

});